# Devexpress can not find controls on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

> Error :The name "  " does not exist in the current context

I got this error for all devexpress controls.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using DevExpress.Data;
using DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView;
using DevExpress.Web.ASPxFileManager;
using BPM.Layer.DataTypes;
using BPM.Layer.UIFClass;
using BPM.Layer.DataOpr;
using BPM.Layer;

    namespace BPM.Ihracat.UI.Tahsilatlar
{
    public partial class Tahsilatlar : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    Operate DOpr = new Operate();
    DataHelper dh = new DataHelper();
    LogClass log = new LogClass();
    BPM.Layer.DataTypes.logininfo giris = new BPM.Layer.DataTypes.logininfo();
    UIFObjects UIO = new UIFObjects();
    DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView grd = new DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView();
    IhracatClass ihr = new IhracatClass();
    DataSet fds = new DataSet();
    DataTable grdTable = new DataTable();
    bool isWriting = false;
    string departman = "0";


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString.Count == 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Giris.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            string ticket = Request.QueryString[0].ToString();
            UIO.getbpmsession(ticket, giris);
        }
        if (Request.QueryString.Count == 2)
        {   
/*islemId is a label*/
/*  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="islemid" Visible="false"></asp:Label>*/

            islemId.Text = Request.QueryString[1].ToString();
        }

        string progname = Request.Url.LocalPath.ToString();
        isWriting = DOpr.getifuserhaswriting(giris.UserID, DOpr.ProgIDofPage(progname));
        DataTable usrdt = DOpr.getKullaniciData(giris.UserID.ToString());
        departman = usrdt.Rows[0]["DepartmanID"].ToString();
        Button btnHiddenTemp=(Button)Page.FindControl("btnHidden");
      // btnHidden.Click += new EventHandler(btnHidden_Click);

      ( (Button)Page.FindControl("btnHidden")).Click += new EventHandler(btnHidden_Click);

        preparetitle();
        preparegrid();


        PrepareCombobox();
    }
```

I can fix the problem like that. Is there any solution to fix this?
I think Visual Studio cannot find all the required references.What should i do ?

Comment: Are you using master page in your project?

Comment: No, I'm not using masterpage.

Comment: Its look like error is somewhere else please put some more code.

Comment: I deleted the designer.cs ,"Convert to Web Application"  on .aspx  page ,it's working now .

Comment: This makes no sense...